# Line formatting with spacing

Tags: vb.net, string.format

Ok I'm just trying to make the `mail.body` part of my `smtp email sub` look nice. So far I have this code:

```
With myStringBuilder
    .AppendLine("Golfer Name" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "Average Quota")
    .AppendLine(vbCrLf)

    For Each row As DataRow In golfersTable.Rows
       .Append(String.Format("{0,-10}{1,40}", row.Item("Golfer Name"), row.Item("Average Quota")))
    Next
End With

mail.Body = myStringBuilder.ToString
```

I'm trying to get the two columns to line up in the body so it looks nice, so far this is the outcome:

```
Golfer Name                                          Average Quota


B                                                               20
J                                                              0
D                                                              28.375
C                                                               16.5
```

Any ideas as to how I can get them to perfectly align with each other? I havent had much practice with `String.Format()` so it's very well possible I messed up the second argument in that... Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Where are you using `String.Format`?

Comment: @false Omg lol, for some reason the `String.Format()` got deleted when I copied it over.. whoops, It's in the edit now, thank you for noticing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I did not test it, but hopefully it gets you going in the right direction and excuse any typos VB.NET is not my native language.

```
With myStringBuilder
    .AppendLine("Golfer Name" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "Average Quota")
    .AppendLine(vbCrLf)

    For Each row As DataRow In golfersTable.Rows
      .AppendFormat("{0,-10}{1}{1}{1}{1}{2:f3}", row["name"], vbTab, row["avgQuota"]).AppendLine()
    Next
End With
```

This will align the data to the same spacing as the headers. I use C# so I was not certain how a tab is represented inside a string so I just use the {1} place the tab 4 times, there might be a better way to do this, in C# I would have had "\t\t\t\t" but I am not sure that works in VB.NET.

Comment: what does `{2:f3}` signify? I've never seen that before

Comment: After the 2 selects the second argument so it is the same as {2}, after the ':' you can specify the string formatting specifications and 'f3' indicates that the item should be formatted as a floating point number with 3 decimal places.